# Monitoring linux processes

Tags: linux, top

Is there an option for linux `top` command where i can filter processes by name?

For example, I only want to monitor python processes (there are several of them), and I'd like to do something like `top -option "python"` or something like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you want information on processes, the answer is always `ps`

It is simple, and yet it has a ridiculous number of options.

Try this one:

```
ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | sort -k 1 -r | head -10
```

Should give you the top 10, by cpu usage.

Comment: In the OP's case you want to grep for python before sorting

Comment: wow, ps rocks! This command did it: `watch "ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | grep python"`. Funny thing is that `watch` ends up in the output as well, because its command contains "python" :-)

Comment: try: watch "ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | grep [p]ython"

Answer (score 2):

This approximates the output of `top`:

```
watch 'ps axo pid,user,pri,nice,vsz,rsz,size,s,pcpu,pmem,time,cmd|grep "[p]ython\|PID USER"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always do "top | grep python" but I'm assuming you want something more dynamic

Comment: Won't work: top's output is dynamic and is not grepable.

Comment: Actually this will work on almost all systems (top is usually smart about not doing dynamic updates if it's being piped - you'll get one screen and an exit).  You can also run `top -d[count]` (at least on FreeBSD) to get [count] displays.

Comment: `top | grep "python"` doesn't do anything

Comment: Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

My Perl skills are basics, but to get a real Top filtered by name, save this code to a file called topn.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

shift @ARGV;
$name = shift @ARGV;
@pids = `/bin/ps -eo pid,user,args | /bin/grep   $name   | /bin/grep -v grep |   /usr/bin/tr -s " "  `;

$arg = "";
foreach (@pids) {
        $_ =~ /^\s([0-9]+)\s/;
        $pid = $1;
        $arg .= " p $pid " if $pid != "";
}

exec("/usr/bin/top $arg @ARGV");
```

Usage: `topn.pl -n FOO c 2` where FOO is the process name to be be grep. The rest of the args are passed to top.

Top accepts at max 20 PID as arguments.